# Funcion String2Punto en MIPS

Tags: c, ensamblador, mips32

Tengo que hacer una función que transforme una cadena del tipo "(+120, 1)" a un objeto de tipo punto almacenado en memoria. Tiene que admitir los espacios en blanco y los signos.

La especificación de la función es como sigue:

- Parámetros:

  - `$a0` : `input_cad`
  - `$a1` : `output_punto (.space)`
- Retorno :

  - `$v0` : `salida_error`
- Códigos de error:

  - `0`: Punto correcto
  - `1`: Sintaxis incorrecta
  - `2`: Overflow en coordenada
  - `3`: Número de dimensiones incorrecto
- Prototipo:

```
int String2Punto( char *input_cad , Punto *output_punto ) ;
```

Mi función pasa todos los casos correctamente salvo cuando la primera coordenada del punto es negativa y la segunda positiva, ¿cómo puedo arreglarlo?

```
#STRING2PUNTO-------------------------------------
String2Punto:

    #Saves in stack
    addi $sp, $sp, -16
    sw $s0, 0($sp)      #nums
    sw $s1, 4($sp)      #strNum
    sw $s2, 8($sp)      #Index
    sw $s3, 12($sp)     #address        
    
    li $s0, 0
    move $s1, $a0
    move $s3, $a1       #address
    move $t9, $s3       #address first direction
    
    lb $t1, 0($s1)
    
    addi $t8,$zero,1    #contador de coordenadas del punto
    addi $s3,$s3,4      #nums[i+1]
    
    li $v0, 1       #set $v0 to 1
    li $t3, 1       #Initialize sign
    li $s2, 10      #Constant
    li $t6, 0       #0 if searching num 1 if searching also ,
    bne $t1, '(',err1       #fin si no hay parentesis
    addi $s1,$s1,1
loop:   
    #Overflow check
    srl $t2, $s0, 31
     
    #Char cases 
    lb $t1, 0($s1)
    beq $t1, '+', check #Branch if eq. than '+'
    beq $t1, '-', chNeg #Branch if eq. than '-'

    beq $t1, ' ', keep  #Branch if eq. than ' '
    beq $t1, ')', end
    
    beqz $t6, coma
    beq $t1, ',',keepC      #pasamos a la siguiente coordenada
coma:
    
    #Check digits
    blt $t1, '0', err1
    bgt $t1, '9', err1
    li $t6, 1
    
    addi $t1, $t1, -48
    
    beq $t3, 1, posit 
    
    mulu $s0, $s0, $s2
    subu $s0, $s0, $t1
    
    srl $t5, $s0, 31
    
    bne $t2, $t5, ovflow    
    
    li $v0, 0
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    j loop
posit:
    mulu $s0, $s0, $s2
    
    addu $s0, $t1, $s0
    
    #Overflow check
    srl $t5, $s0, 31
    
    bne $t2, $t5, ovflow    
    
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    li $v0, 0
    
    j nocheck       #If jumps here it means its a digit
chNeg:  
    li $t3, -1      #To know when a num is neg
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    lb $t1, 0($s1)
    
    beq $t1, '+', check #Branch if eq. than '+'
    beq $t1, '-', chNeg #Branch if eq. than '-'
    beq $t1, ' ', err1  #Branch if eq. than ' '
    
    #Check digits
    blt $t1, '0', err1
    bgt $t1, '9', err1
    li $t6, 1
    
    addi $t1, $t1, -48
    mul $s0, $s0, $t3
    mul $s0, $s0, $s2
    sub $s0, $s0, $t1
    
    #li $v1, 0
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    j loop
check:  
    li $t3, 1
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    lb $t1, 0($s1)
    
    beq $t1, '+', check #Branch if eq. than '+'
    beq $t1, '-', chNeg #Branch if eq. than '-'
    beq $t1, ' ', err1  #Branch if eq. than ' '
    
    #Check digits+
    blt $t1, '0', err1
    bgt $t1, '9', err1
    li $t6, 1
     
    addi $t1, $t1, -48
    mul $s0, $s0, $s2
    add $s0, $t1, $s0
    
    li $v1, 0
keep:   
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    j loop
keepC:  
    sw $s0,0($s3)       #Save num in memory and reset stuff     
    addi $s3,$s3,4      #nums[i+1]
    addi $s0,$zero,0
    addi $t3,$zero,0
    li $t6, 0
    addi $t8,$t8,1      #agrega 1 al contador de dimensiones
    addi $t5,$zero,0            #despues tiene que ser un digito
    lb $t1, 1($s1)
    bne $t1, ' ', noespacio
    addi $s1,$s1,1
    j loop
    #Check digits+
noespacio:  
    beq $t1, '+', check #Branch if eq. than '+'
    beq $t1, '-', chNeg #Branch if eq. than '-'
    blt $t1, '0', err1
    bgt $t1, '9', err1
    li $t6, 1
    
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    
nocheck:
    j loop
ovflow:
    li $v1, 2
end:    
    lb $t1, 1($s1)
    bne $t1, '\0', err1
    sw $s0,0($s3)       #Save num[n-1] in memory
    blt $t8,2,err3      #dimensiones no adecuadas
    bgt $t8,3,err3
    j noerr

noerr:  
    sw $t8, 0($t9)      #num[0] = dimension
    li $v0, 0
    #Restore the stack
desapilar: 
    lw $s0, 0($sp)
    lw $s1, 4($sp)
    lw $s2, 8($sp)
    lw $s3, 12($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 16
    
    #returns
    jr $ra

err1:   #li $v1,1
    li $v0,1
    j desapilar
err3:   #li $v1,3
    li $v0,3
    j desapilar
```